# How to handle bounded [0,1] dependent variable that causes one to fail heteroscedasticity

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, heteroscedasticity

In my particular situation, our outcome variable is recall (bounded between 0 and 1 inclusive), and we are building a linear mixed effects model in R. We end up with a qq plot like the one below:

[image: qq-plot-residuals]

Is there anything to do to deal with the bounded outcome variable? Any transformations I make will also be bounded, so I don't see how to get around this. Or is the general idea to just do any transformation I can to get the residuals as close to constant variance as possible, and the shape caused by the bounds isn't a big deal?

Some similar questions:

- [Effect of baseline on change over time in mixed models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231755/effect-of-baseline-on-change-over-time-in-mixed-models/231968#231968)
- [Continuous dependent variable with upper and lower bounds: logit transformation appropriate?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/245884/continuous-dependent-variable-with-upper-and-lower-bounds-logit-transformation/322248#322248)
- [Using t-test/ANOVA on bounded data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207483/using-t-test-anova-on-bounded-data)

Comment: Why not analyze your data using the zero-one inflated beta regression mixed effects modeling using the glmmTMB package, for example? See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/glmmTMB.pdf.

Comment: I don't think glmmTMB can do zero-one inflation (only zero-inflation) ? But you could shrink the data a little bit inward to get (0,1) (e.g. see Smithson and Verkuilen's "better lemon-squeezer" paper)

Comment: It looks like you might have discrete denominators in your data (downward-sloping linear features in your residual plot); can you use a binomial model?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement I did not think to use that (nor did I know about it)! However, as Ben pointed out, this package only does zero inflation. The main issue is that this is becoming way too complex for the community I am writing for (in fact, linear mixed-effects models are pushing it already)... So I guess I am wondering how robust linear mixed effects models are to this sort of violation of assumptions?

Comment: @BenBolker The denominators are discrete; the measure is recall (tp / (tp + fn)). However, each observation (a user, in this case) may have a different number in the denominator, which makes me think that a binomial model cannot be used... Does that sound right to you? (I haven't used binomial models in awhile)

Comment: you absolutely can use a binomial model, and that would be the right thing to do.  In `lme4` either `cbind(tp,fn) ~ ...` *or* `tp/(tp+fn) ~ ..., weights=tp+fn)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really had [0,1] data with no definable denominator, you could use a mixed model with a Beta-distributed response (e.g. in the `glmmTMB` or `brms` packages in R), but you would need to do something about the exact 0 and 1 values (which are not feasible for a Beta response - they have likelihood density of either 0 or infinity unless the shape parameters are exactly (1,1)), e.g. shift them slightly toward 0.5 (see e.g. Smithson and Verkuilen *Psychological Methods* 2006).

However, based on the appearance of your residual plot (discrete linear features) and the comment

> the measure is recall (`tp / (tp + fn)`). However, each observation (a user, in this case) may have a different number in the denominator ...

I would recommend that you use a binomial model. In `lme4` (and other R packages) you can either (1) specify the response as a two-column response `cbind(success,failure) ~ ...` or (2) specify the proportion `tp/(tp+fn) ~ ...` as the response, and include a `weights` argument that gives the denominator (`tp+fn`).